# Used iPhone 3G 16G - Worth anything?

Tags: iphone, apple-store

I currently have a an iPhone 5 64GB I am using and a iPhone 3 16GB I am not using. Planning to upgrade to the iPhone 6 when it comes out later this year.

I've heard Apple will give you cash off purchase for trade in. Does anyone know what they might give me if I trade one or both in, and whether a combination trade would even be considered?

Or, would I be better off selling on my own?

Comment: 5G isn't a model, do you mean iPhone 5?

Comment: Have you checked eBay? That will probably be your best source of relative prices. And I would be surprised if a combination trade would net you any benefit.

Comment: @dwightk If you do a strict generation count on iPhones - 5G is 4S and 3G is 3GS. My brain hurts to write that.

Comment: @bmike yeah, but with "6G when it comes out later this year" I was guessing the generation count wasn't too strict.

Answer (score 1):

Although newer iPhones get substantial value (iPhone 4S + 64GB AT&T is up to $150 today), iPhone 3 and 3GS are rapidly becoming worthless in the US. Your phone is may still be worth money in a rebate or gift cart in USA if you exchange it as part of a phone purchase. Apple has an official relationship with PowerOn where the staff in each store checks market conditions from that third party and quotes you an offer when you are shopping.

Apple's plan is documented at http://apple.com/recycling and currently in the US, you can only trade in one device for each iPhone purchase. You can go to that site now and see if they will offer any money, but I'm seeing $0 currently.

Apple staff are trained in evaluating the condition of devices, so you'll get a better read on the price you'll get by having that second opinion. Some people feel their phone is flawless when it isn't. Others mark a phone down for things that would actually fetch price for excellent condition. You can do a little research before going in to the Apple store on:

- http://gazelle.com
- http://ebay.com (prices here will likely be both higher and lower than what you will get from a company that does Apple's trade in *which means you have to do more work to get a fair number*)
- http://amazon.com (search for your model and look for **Trade In** in the right side of the web page under the buy now/add to cart button)

I would also research what your local cell carriers have for current promotions. If there is an in-store, verifiable special. You can ask Apple Retail to match the brick and mortar offers if there are case / charger deals locally when you buy.

If Apple's deal isn't good enough, look for a carrier or Radio Shack that have $50 for any phone trade in and see what's the best deal overall. I can't imagine it not going for $15 if you put it on ebay for 0.01 and no reserve, but that's a bit more of a gamble than if you were to get an offer from a company that buys used devices.

Comment: I don't know the prices in the US but here in Switzerland a mint iPhone 3G 16GB (with no scratches etc.) will sell for CHF 20-30 (which is about $20-30). So don't expect to gain very much here :-)

Comment: @patrix The value in the US has plummeted and the OP will be lucky to get value if they bought a new phone today and would probably have to buy from a retailer other than Apple to get gift cards in exchange for recycling anything older than iPhone 4.

Comment: I think at the end of your second paragraph you forgot to finish the sentence :D